# screen tearing in my intel integrated laptop

Tags: drivers

I'm experiencing screen tearing issues with my laptop, which has an Intel i3-1005G1 CPU and Intel Iris Plus Graphics G1. Despite trying various troubleshooting steps.
Could you please provide suggestions or solutions to help me eliminate screen tearing on my laptop?

Comment: Providing your OS/product & release details are a starting point... we currently have no idea as to what Ubuntu product, what release etc. you're using. Also providing details as to what you tried is helpful unless you wish us to repeat those steps.